# PHP Handle Timed Calls

Tags: php, daemon

I'm building a small browser game with PHP and I've some events like building buildings which have to call a method after a given time (complete building). My plan to handle that:

- player clicks on a building
- a specific class name, method name, attributes and the specific time will be stored in a db table
- run a PHP daemon which fetch the entries and call them

So far my idea. Are there any (better) ways to handle that?

Comment: I think you'll have to store the time the action was started, then compare that on each request to see if it was a certain time ago. To be honest, PHP isn't the best tool for this because it's stateless. I think you'd be better off using Javascript where you can just run a loop indefinitely.

Comment: Well, that is why I want to use a dameon. To get rid of the stateless check after each request. And yes, I forgot to mention the time, but this will be stored as well. JS isn't a choice (except node.js). It's frontend and we are talking about backend changes.

Comment: If you do opt for using a deamon, take a look at http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net which will daemonise your PHP code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to send some kind of notifications on finish to user when he is not online (emails or so) You will have to create some kind of deamon.

If You don't need it, just check for it on request.
So You store start time in db and on each request check if enough time passed. If user is online You use javascript to make a request at time the task is supposed to finish.

Comment: I don't have to send mails etc. (at the moment), but checking on each request could be a problem if there is a lot to do. The daemon would be separated by the normal flow. Problem could be if you make changes on the db without any transactions.

Comment: But You don't check for all possible actions in whole application but just one related to current request. I don't know how big Your game is but I believe there won't be so many simultaneous actions going at the same time for one user to make request too expensive.

Comment: Ok, but what is about actions which are not related to the current user, but are even important. Maybe build a building and change the highscore or such a things. The requests would have to know what they may affect, right? That sounds complicated.

Comment: Ranking can be updated periodically e.g. every hour. Make a class that will handle updates of one user only and run it if You going to do anything related to that user. It is at each request You will check for any pending/active/finished actions of current user and if he is watching other users or in any way related update them as well.

Comment: Ok, ranking was a bad example. But what is about buildings which give a special benefit for the user. It shouldn't wait for the next request from the user. It should give the benefit at the moment the building is built. How to handle that without a daemon?

Comment: You miss the point. If user is offline and no one is attacking/viewing him or whatever his status is irrelevant. When comes a request involving given user first thing You do is to update his status, dispatch any pending actions calculate his resources and stuff. Point to be made is that making a deamon is good option but it is easier to make it on request.